# Akka and singleton actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-http, akka-actor

I've recently started messing around with akka's actors and http modules. However I've stumbled upon a rather annoying little quirk, namely, creating singelton actors.

Here are two examples:

1)

I have an in-memory cache, my service is quite small (its an app rather) so I really like this in memory model. I can hold most information relevant to the user in a Map (well, a map of lists, but still, quite an easy to reason about structure) and I don't get the overhead and complexity of a redis, geode or aerospike.

The only problem is that this in-memory chache can be modified, by multiple sources and said modifications must be synchronous. Instead of synchornizing all 3 acess methods for this structure (e.g. by building a message queue or implementing locks) I thought I'd just wrap the structure and its access methods into an actor, build in message queue, easy receive->send logic and if things scale up it will be very easy to replace with a DA actors over a dedicated in memory db.

2) I have a "Service" layer that should be used to dispatch actors for various jobs (access the database, access the in-memory cache, do this computation with data and deliver the result to the user... etc).

It makes sense of this Service layer to be a "singleton" of sorts, a closure over some functions, since it does nothing that's blocking or cpu/memory intensive in any way, it simply assigns tasks further down the line (e.g. decides how many actors/thread/w.e should be created and where a request should go)

However, this thing would require either:

a) Making both object singleton actors or

b) Making both objects actual "objects"(as in the scala object notation that designates a single named singleton with functions that have closures over its scope)

There are plenty of problems with b), namely that the service layer will either have to get an actors system "passed" to it (and I'm not sure that's a best practice) in order o create actors, rather than creating its own "childrens" it will create children's using the global actors system and the messaging and monitoring logic will be a lot more awkward and unintuitive. Also, that the in-memory cache will not have the advantage of the built in message que (I'm not saying its hard to implement one, but this seems like one of those situation where one goes "Oh, jolly, its good that I have actors and I don't have to spend time implementing and testing this code")

a) seems to have the problem of being generally speaking poorly documented and unadvised in the akka documentation. I mean:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-singleton.html

Look at this shit, half of the docs are warning against using it, it was its own dependency and quite frankly its very hard to read for a poor sod like me which hasn't set foot in the functional&concurrent programming ivory tower.

So, ahm. Could any of you guys explain to me why its bad to use singleton actors ? How do you design singletons if they can't be actors ? Is there any way to design singleton actors that won't cause a lot of damage down the line ? Is the whole "service" model of having "global" services that are called rather than instantiated "un akka like" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify the documentation, they're not warning against using it.  They're warning that there are circumstances in which using a singleton will cause problems, which are expected given the circumstances.  They mention the following situations:

- If the singleton is a performance bottleneck.  This makes sense.  If everything relies on a single object that does work slowly, everything will be slow.
- If the actor needs to be non-stop available, you'll run into problems if the singleton ever goes down, because those messages can't just be handled by another instance.  It will take some amount of time to re-start the singleton before its work can be resumed.
- The biggest problem happens if you have auto-downing turned on.  Auto-downing is a policy by which an unreachable node is assumed to be down, and removed from the network.  If you do this, but the node is not actually down but just unreachable due to a network partition, both sides of the partition will decide that they're the surviving nodes and create their own singletons.  So now you have two singletons.  Which is, of course, not what you want from a singleton.  But you should never use auto-downing outside of testing anyway.  It's a terrible recovery strategy that was included for completeness and convenience in testing.

So I don't read that as recommending against using it.  Just being clear about the expected pitfalls if you do use it, based on the nature of the structure.